# How is this curve of intersection is derived?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, parametric

Can anyone tell me how are parametric equations derived based on the hyperboloid of 1 sheet formula shown in the image?

Clearly my request is beyond what the textbook question is asking here and I successfully completed the task of graphing it, please see the image below. it's a very pretty curve overlaying on the hyperboloid of 1 sheet. It's very interesting to me to understand how to generate a curve or any curve that would overlap on top of the a shape like this.

**strong text**

[image: The question]

**strong text**[image: The curve of intersection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider cylindrical coordinates $r, \theta, z$.
The given hyperboloid has equation $(12r)^2-(5z)^2=10^2$, and is thus given by the revolution of the $r,z$ hyperbola around the $z$ axis.
Now, concerning your question, on how to generate a general curve that lays on that surface
it is clear that we can always put
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \theta  = \theta (t) \hfill \\
  z = z(\theta ) \hfill \\
  r = \frac{1}
{{12}}\sqrt {10^{\,2}  + \left( {5z} \right)^{\,2} }  = \frac{{10}}
{{12}}\sqrt {1 + \left( {\frac{z}
{2}} \right)^{\,2} }  \hfill \\
  x = r\cos \theta  \hfill \\
  y = r\sin \theta  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
As for the example you gave, we can write
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x = 27/26\sin \left( {8t} \right) - 8/39\sin \left( {18t} \right) = 27/26\cos \left( {8t - \pi /2} \right) + 8/39\cos \left( {18t + \pi /2} \right) \hfill \\
  y =  - 27/26\cos \left( {8t} \right) + 8/39\cos \left( {18t} \right) = 27/26\sin \left( {8t - \pi /2} \right) + 8/39\sin \left( {18t + \pi /2} \right) \hfill \\
  z = 144/65\sin \left( {5t} \right) = \frac{{144}}
{{65}}\sqrt {\frac{{1 - \cos \left( {10t} \right)}}
{2}}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
wherefrom we get that $P=(x,y)$ is the composition of two circular orbits, as depicted in this figure

[image: curva_iperb_2]

In fact, regarding $r$ we have that:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  r^{\,2}  = x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2}  = \left( { - 27/26} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {8/39} \right)^{\,2}  - 2\left( {27/26} \right)\left( {8/39} \right)\left( {\cos \left( {8t} \right)\cos \left( {18t} \right) + \sin \left( {8t} \right)\sin \left( {18t} \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{13^{\,2} }}\left( {\frac{{3^{\,6} }}
{{2^{\,2} }} + \frac{{2^{\,6} }}
{{3^{\,2} }}} \right) - 2\frac{1}
{{13^{\,2} }}\left( {\frac{{3^{\,3} }}
{2}\frac{{2^{\,3} }}
{3}} \right)\cos \left( {10t} \right) = \frac{1}
{{13^{\,2}  \cdot 2^{\,2}  \cdot 3^{\,2} }}\left( {3^{\,8}  + 2^{\,8}  - 2 \cdot 3^{\,4}  \cdot 2^{\,4} \cos \left( {10t} \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{13^{\,2} 2^{\,2} 3^{\,2} }}\left( {\left( {3^{\,8}  + 2^{\,8} } \right) - 2\left( {3^{\,4} 2^{\,4} } \right)\left( {\cos ^{\,2} \left( {5t} \right) - \sin ^{\,2} \left( {5t} \right)} \right)} \right) = \left( {\frac{5}
{6}} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {\frac{{12}}
{{13}}} \right)^{\,2} \sin ^{\,2} \left( {5t} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
and
$$
\begin{gathered}
  r^{\,2}  = \frac{{10^{\,2}  + \left( {5z} \right)^{\,2} }}
{{12^{\,2} }} = \frac{{100}}
{{144}}\left( {1 + \left( {72/65\sin \left( {5t} \right)} \right)^{\,2} } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {\frac{5}
{6}} \right)^{\,2} \left( {1 + \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{{72}}
{{65}}} \right)^{\,2} \left( {1 - \cos \left( {10t} \right)} \right)} \right) = \frac{1}
{{13^{\,2}  \cdot 2^{\,2}  \cdot 3^{\,2} }}\left( {3^{\,8}  + 2^{\,8}  - 2 \cdot 3^{\,4}  \cdot 2^{\,4} \cos \left( {10t} \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {\frac{5}
{6}} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {\frac{{12}}
{{13}}} \right)^{\,2} \sin ^{\,2} \left( {5t} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
so demonstrating that the point $P$ is on the given hyperboloid.

Now we can derive the value of $\theta (t)$  to complete the exemplification, and we can do it better geometrically from the figure above.
However, since it is not immediate, I will omit it herewith.

Comment: Sorry, in previous version of my answer there was a missmatch concerning the angle reference in the picture (which actually should have been from the y axis and ccw): nothing affecting the substance, but to get a clear rendering I amended for that, either in the picture and in the preceding formula.